# iPhone server interaction

Tags: php, iphone

What is the best way to pass data to an iPhone from a server through http? CSV, XML, JSON, ... ?

a) I am required to pass three alpha-numeric (40 char max) strings

b) I am required to pass a key-value pair array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries for use for all of the formats and they are all easy to implement.  Go with whichever is easiest for your server to provide.

If you need key/value pairs, you could also send it as a plist.

Comment: And to process a plist in PHP you can use: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList

Answer (score 2):

JSON is all you need. I doesn't get simpler.
As Framework i recommend [SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want data to contain a key value pair format , You can use XMl .

Comment: Whilst I like XML; JSON is much easier to process in PHP than XML.

Comment: @Flukey: absolutely - see the Angle Bracket Tax (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/xml-the-angle-bracket-tax.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not only is JSON really easy, it is not built into iOS 5.0.